# Download the streaming m3u8 video from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, download, html5-video, chromedp

Im trying to download video from the below html code.

> Please note Im going to run this inside Golang `chromedp` code.

Which can be found at `https://www.zee5.com/tvshows/details/bhabi-ji-ghar-par-hain/0-6-199/bhabi-ji-ghar-par-hain-episode-343-june-21-2016-full-episode/0-1-532`

```
<video class="jw-video jw-reset" tabindex="-1" disableremoteplayback="" webkit-playsinline="" playsinline="" id="0-1-532" src="blob:https://www.zee5.com/f27564d0-214b-49e2-a3d8-2b8b1314f05f" style="object-fit: fill;"></video>
```

The problem is if you inspect Network tab, you will find the this in the network
`https://netst4z5x-vh.akamaihd.net/i/draco/shows/and_tv/Bhabiji_Ghar_Par_Hai/June/21062016/Bhabiji_Ghar_Par_Hai_Episode_343_Ozee.smil/master.m3u8?hdnea=st=1575885515~exp=1575888515~acl=/*~hmac=8f4d35fe89877d455ae614f88ea9c9cf2241ae6ab1bdbbd1790f8376863fd94d`

but **network** tab keep making a new request for video, hence making each previous link obsolete

see the screenshot below
[image]

Comment: Look at these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188332/download-ts-files-from-video-stream).

Yesterday, I tried to download a streaming video. I've got a m3u8 link using a chrome extension and then pasted it to VLC Media Player. But it was too slowly and I watched a movie online)

Comment: @OleksandrLunov thanks for the reply. but is there a way without extension? Im going to try this inside `chromedp` golang